# Spring Boot auto configuration order from external dependency

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-boot

I have a problem trying to get my autoconfiguration working. I have two jars as follows, each have a spring.factories file where these two are enabled for EnableAutoConfigurationProperties.

This configuration is in my-package-mock.jar, it depends on my-package-real.jar below:

```
package org.packages.package.packageA;
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(AutoConfigurationB.class)
public class AutoConfigurationA {

    @Bean
    public MyService mockService() {
        return new MyMockService();
    }
}
```

This configuration is in my-package-real.jar:

```
package org.packages.package.packageB;
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyService.class)
public class AutoConfigurationB {

    @Bean
    public MyService realService() {
        return new MyRealService();
    }
}
```

Now the idea is that if my-package-mock.jar is included then AutoConfigurationB will not be processed as A is ordered to be before and by the time it gets to B MyService is already defined.
However, it does not work when used in a third project that includes these jars. It looks like the AutoConfigureOrder annotation is skipped when loading these jars from the classpath and these configurations are processed in the order the jvm loads these classes. In my particular case it does B first and at that point MyService is not yet defined and thus will instantiate the RealService bean. How can I get this to work?

Obviously this is a small example where a @Primary annotation on the mock will do the job, but that is not what I'm looking for.

Edit: it seems if the @SpringBootApplication annotated main is not a part of the package where these configurations are then things do work. E.g. the annotation is not in "org.packages.package" but "org.somewhereelse" then things work.

```
package org.packages.package;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Collections.singletonList(TestApplication.class).toArray(), args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@AutoConfigureBefore` and `@AutoConfigureAfter` only apply when a configuration class is loaded as a result of auto-configuration being enabled and it being listed in `spring.factories`. When your auto-configuration classes are in `org.packages.package` (or a sub-package) and your main application class is in the same package, they're being found by Spring Framework's standard component scanning. This happens because `@SpringBootApplication` enables component scanning for the package of the class that it's annotating. As a result of this the auto-configuration-specific ordering doesn't apply.

To avoid the problem, you should places your auto-configuration classes in a package that isn't used by any application code.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that is indeed what solved my problem. The strange think was that when both configuration classes and @SpringBootApplication where used on their own (e.g. not as a dependency jar in another project) they worked correctly. I don't know if that was just luck, or that spring-boot behaves differently in that case. Eithee way, answer accepted. Thanks!

Comment: I am experiencing similar issue with `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`. If `@Configuration` class is in the same package, everything works OK and my `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)` results in "asap" Bean definition, but once this class is placed into separate package , it is not processed "asap" and it result in different ordering of Bean definition.  I am struggling to understand how @AutoConfigureOrder functionality is influenced by placing the class to separate package.

Comment: @walter33 perhaps the class is being picked up by component scanning in one location and not in the other? That's only I guess as it's impossible to tell without more information. A separate question with a minimal reproducible example would be the best way to dig into this further.