# Spring Boot - Prioritize Bean Creation Order from External Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following auto-configured class, listed in `spring.factories` under `EnableAutoConfiguration` and packaged as a common library:

```
@Configuration
public class GracefulShutdownConfig {

    @Bean
    public GracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown() {
        return new GracefulShutdown();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactory webServerFactory(final GracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(gracefulShutdown);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

When imported as a jar library, the beans get initialized too late, at the point at which the `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` has already started Tomcat, added the `connectorCustomizers` and injected a `Connector` to them.

As a result, the `GracefulShutdown` class does not receive its `Connector` and throws a NullPointerException.

I have read [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515322) on how to prioritize auto-configured classes among auto-configured classes, but in my case I wish the beans of my auto-configured class to get loaded with priority when the Spring Boot itself is starting, as the beans are not related to or dependent on other externally injected beans. Can someone help?

Comment: `@AutoConfigureBefore` seems to be exactly what you need here (though I'd also look to confirm that the default Boot behavior wouldn't apply your customizer if you simply registered it as a bean; this is a fairly common pattern).

Comment: I added this to my configuration class:
@AutoConfigureOrder(-2147483648)
@AutoConfigureBefore({ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class, EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.class})
However, still with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use `@AutoConfigureBefore`.

`@AutoConfigureBefore`, when used on the Spring auto-configuration class `ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration`, which is responsible for the instantiation of `TomcatServletWebServerFactory`, allows us to register our own `BeanDefinition` of `TomcatServletWebServerFactory` before the factory creates its definition

Here is the solution:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(value = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GracefulShutdownConfig {

    @Bean
    public GracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown() {
        return new GracefulShutdown();
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory(final GracefulShutdown gracefulShutdown) {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(gracefulShutdown);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here are two sources that helped me search in the right direction:

- Article, [How Spring Boot auto-configuration works](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/spring-boot-autoconfiguration/)
- Github discussion, [Clarify the effect of ordering auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/22337)

Comment: That's odd. If removing the `@DependsOn` causes a failure, then there's something wrong (either in your configuration or possibly in Boot), since the context should recognize the depends-on automatically from the method parameter.

Comment: If I remove DependsOn, it is still working, thanks, apparently I did not test this final combination. But, if I remove it and return the super type of WebServerFactory instead of TomcatServletWebServerFactory, my connector does not get injected in my class, regardless if I have DependsOn or not. It is  strange to me, but I will leave it there.